# Google Maps Multi Marker not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show multi marker on the map, but it only comes one. When I check console all lat and long values can be seen. But there is only one marker.

This code is my php code.

```
    $query="SELECT lat, lng, FROM mytable limit 5 offset $offset";
    $result = pg_exec($dbconn, $query);
    $response = pg_fetch_all($result);
    $data=json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $data1 = json_decode($data, true);
```

This code is my js code and php code.

```
    function initMap() {
      <?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
    var myLatLng = {lat:<?=$data1[$i]['lat']?>, lng:<?=$data1[$i]['lng']?>};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 19,
      center: myLatLng
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
      <?php } ?>
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you override your map, put your map init outside the loop.

```
function initMap() {
   var center = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 19,
      center: center
  });

  <?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
        var myLatLng = {lat:<?=$data1[$i]['lat']?>, lng:<?=$data1[$i]['lng']?>};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
  <?php } ?>
}
```